# How to save an object into a Dictionary of string?

Tags: c#

I've created a class that use some method of my php rest api. This method return string and sometimes an object. The object rapresent the context of the stack trace. I save this trace inside a `IDictionary`. A little example:

```
IDictionary<string, string> transaction = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public class Details
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string mex { get; set; }
}

public class Context
{
    public List<object> context { get; set; }
}

public class Trace
{
    public Details details { get; set; }
    public Context context { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
   public Trace trace { get; set; }
}


//Parse the json
public IDictionary<string, string> getData()
{
     var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>("the json");

     foreach (var item in obj)
     {
         transaction["date"] = item.trace.details.date;
         transaction["type"] = item.trace.details.type;
         transaction["mex"] = item.trace.details.mex;

        // Get some context

        foreach (var trace in item.trace.context.context)
        {
            transaction["context"] = trace;  //I can't do this is an object
        }
     }
return transaction;
}
```

How you can see the `trace` item is an object, and I can't save it in my `IDictionary`. Some workaround to the problem?

Comment: Why don't you serialize trace with json and save as string like this: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trace)

Comment: @Klaudiuszbryjamus I'll try with it.

Comment: Did you know, that you are saving only last element of list? what kind of data is in the list? Do you want to store it as array or as a string or something else?

Comment: @lukbl Generally the context is just one item.

Comment: @Sandokan so why is it a list? Instead of looping you could just pick first item.

Comment: @lukbl 'cause the json return a list of element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize the object and store it as a string:

```
transaction["context"] = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trace);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `for` loop you could do following.

Concatenate all elements of list, if you don't care about how they are serialized - `ToString()` will be called on each item of the list:

```
 transaction["context"] = string.Join("<separator>",item.trace.context.context);
```

or serialize list as json array using [this library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm):

```
 transaction["context"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.trace.context.context);
```

Again, loop is not necessary